# Why isn't "fciv" command correctly recognized in Batch files with "for" cycles?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, command-line, fciv

Assuming that the `fciv.exe` file has been placed in the system directory `C:\WINDOWS\system32`, it works correctly both when it is recalled from command prompt and when it is used in Batch scripting files. For instance:

```
@echo off
fciv -md5 C:\DOCUME~1\myUsername
pause
```

The above statements work well.
But, if I use `fciv` inside a `for` cycle, as in the following example:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1 delims=/ " %%g in ('fciv -md5 C:\DOCUME~1\myUsername') do (echo %%g)
```

The command is not recognized and an error returns from command prompt:

```
"fciv" is not recognized as internal or external command, etc.
```

The same statement works in command prompt - of course using a `%g` variable.
 In order to be correctly interpreted as a command in `for` cycles inside Batch files, I am forced to use a full path to `fciv.exe` file.
Is anyone able to explain me why this happens?

Comment: It is a long shot, but, does your batch script modify the `%PATH%` variable?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, unfortunately I have just noticed that some lines above, I have defined the output variable of a `set /p` command as `%PATH%`, so it actually replaces the environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MC ND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476/mc-nd) has given already the right answer in a comment which is repeated here as an answer.

The batch file of the questioner contains just `fciv` instead of `fciv.exe` or even better `"Full\Path To\fciv.exe"`.

Therefore Windows first searches in current working directory with `fciv.*` for a file with one of the extensions listed in environment variable **PATHEXT** separated by semi-colons and if no file with such a file extension can be found, in all directories listed in environment variable **PATH** separated also by semi-colons.

And environment variable **PATH** as defined for the user account was additionally modified within the batch file above the line running `fciv` with removing the path to directory containing `fciv.exe`. Therefore Windows could not find this application on execution of the batch file.

**Hint 1:**
For applications called or started within a batch file it is nearly always best to specify the file name of the application with file extension as then Windows can directly search for example for `fciv.exe` instead of `fciv.*` to find a file with extension COM, EXE, BAT, ...

**Hint 2:**
It is even better to specify the file name of a called or started application with full path if the path is fixed for example

- if the batch file is only executed on one computer,
- or the application is installed surely on all computers in same directory,
- or the application is installed on a server only while the batch file is executed by the clients and calling / starting the application via a public share directly on server.

**Conclusion:**

- Poor is:   `fciv`
- Better is: `fciv.exe`
- Best is:   `"Full\Path To\fciv.exe"`

The best reference of an application is not always possible, but referencing application file name with file extension is nearly always possible.